# to bind multiple knockout viewmodel scripts to one view

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to bind two knockout viewmodels to one view. I've read examples and offers like this

```
var viewModel1 = function(){
var self = this;
self.firstName = ko.observable();
self.lastName = ko.observable();
self.fullName = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.firstName + " " + self.lastName;
});
};

var viewModel2 = function(){
var self = this;
self.premium = ko.observable();
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel1(), document.getElementById("container1"));
ko.applyBindings(new viewModel2(), document.getElementById("container2"));
```

but my viewmodels are in the separate js files. How to bind them to the view? For example

```
<script>
   $(function() {
        window.viewModal1 = new CandidatesViewModal();
        window.viewModal2 = new CandidatesViewModal();
    });

        ko.applyBindings(viewModal1 , $('#viewModal1 ').get(0));
        ko.applyBindings(viewModal2 , $('#viewModal2 ').get(0));
</script>
```

but this approach doesn't work. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Each web page is a view. knockout doesn't separate this out (like angular does for example). So you have to have one viewmodel per web page. You need to build a viewmodel, containing both you viewmodels, if you see what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a container view model, e.g. like this:

```
var container = {
  vm1: new viewModel1(),
  vm2: new viewModel2()
}

ko.applyBindings(containerVm);
```

And adjust your view accordingly.

Comment: So, in View I should use it like <textarea data-bind="value: **vm1**.text"></textarea> ?

Comment: Yarp. Or utilize [the `with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html) e.g. on a containing element or with [containerless syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html).